# modalPresentationStyle works strangly

Tags: ios, swift3

I've a simple question,

Why this works perfectly :

```
class HomeController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, AddingDisciplineDelegate, LogoutUserDelegate {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()
               let controller = SeePlugAlertModalView()
               controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen       
               self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        (...)
}

class SeePlugAlertModalView : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.isOpaque = false
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    }
```

[image]

But if i put the modalPresentationStyle in SeePlugAlertView, my view is presented but hides the parent view controller. ( Even if the background color has an alpha of 0.5).

```
 class HomeController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, AddingDisciplineDelegate, LogoutUserDelegate {
                override func viewDidLoad() {
                       super.viewDidLoad()
                       let controller = SeePlugAlertModalView()       
                       self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                (...)
        }

class SeePlugAlertModalView : UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                self.view.isOpaque = false
                self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
      }
```

[image]

Comment: I think that the problem is that in the second case you are calling first `present` and then the `modalPresentationStyle` is changed. What would happen if you called `_ = controller.view` before `self.present`?

Comment: So how can set modalPresentationStyle before the `present`? in a constructor that i will create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in your second code, by the time SeePlugAlertModalView's `viewDidLoad` is called, *it's too late;* the presentation of SeePlugAlertModalView has already started. So, since you've removed the earlier configuration from HomeController, there is *no* setting of the presentation style at presentation time, and you're getting `.fullScreen` (the default).

The solution is to set SeePlugAlertModalView's presentation style *earlier*, such as in its initializer or `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: That doesn't work even in the awakeFromNib, I set in SeePlugAlertModalView `override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    }`

Comment: I created a constructor like that : `init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    }
    ` and that  solved my problem :)

Comment: It doesn't work in `awakeFromNib` because this view controller doesn't come from a nib. It does work for view controllers that do come from a nib.

Comment: If the viewcontroller does not come from a nib then you need to override: `initWithNibName:bundle:`